# Swift XCTest UI tests with Realm

Tags: swift, testing, realm, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm developing my UI test with Swift 3.0 using Realm 2.4.2.

#### UI test target

- create realm object Cat with pk "cat_01"
- check if exists a Cat object  with pk "cat_01" -> success
- open view controller that contains a list of cats fetched from realm -> empty list

#### Application

- CatsListViewController: a table view with cats (no Cat object are found)

---

How can I "see" both on test target and application same realm objects?

What I do **not** want to do is using the `launchArguments` workaround delegating app to create objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "see" the same Realm objects in your UITest target and your Application because those two are running as completely separated processes.

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html):

> UI testing exercises your app's UI in the same way that users do
>   without access to your app's internal methods, functions, and
>   variables. ... Your test code runs as a separate process, synthesizing
>   events that UI in your app responds to.

In other words: Your UITests are running in a separate App that interacts with your main App (when you run a UITest you can see the Testrunner App being launched and closed before your main App is being launched). Those two apps can not share objects.

I see two directions that you could go:

**1. Create the cat objects via your app's UI**

Somewhere you probably have a "Add cat" button. Press that in your UITest, add a cat like a use would and then assert that the cat has been added to the list. That is what UITests are for. Using the app like a user would and testing the results of a user's interaction with the app.

**2. Use UnitTests:**

If you want to test that a created Realm cat object is populating a list a UnitTest might be the better way. During a UnitTest you have full access to your app's code. So you can create a cat object in your test code and the app will "see" it.